# Node MySQL: Transaction with Varying Queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, node-mysql

## The Problem

I'm trying to develop a simple framework for my node.js app that will allow me to pass a variable sequence of queries of all kinds to fire, based upon the context and what I need to accomplish.

The difficulty is that, when it comes to insert/update/delete statements, it's like the module is failing to commit the transaction, and the database is remaining unaffected--this is happening for both individual queries, and queries in transaction, which is especially strange for the transactions (where I'm calling conn.commit() at the end).

## The Barebones Code

Differences: there's a result parsing script that can also be supplied dynamically, in case special handling is needed based on inserted rows.

```
function runTransaction(queries)
{
    var tranResults = {};
    var tranDef = Promise.defer();
    connection.beginTransaction(function(err){
        if(err instanceof Error)
        {
            tranDef.reject(err);
            connection.rollback();
            return;
        }
        let index = -1;
        function runTransactionQueries()
        {
            if(index >= queries.length)
            {
                connection.commit();
                tranDef.resolve(tranResults);
                return;
            }
            index++;
            let query = queries[index];
            connection.query(query, function(err, result){
                if(err instanceof Error)
                {
                    tranDef.reject(err);
                    connection.rollback();
                    return;
                }
                tranResults[index] = result;
                return runTransactionQueries();
            })
        }
        return runTransactionQueries();
    }
    return tranDef.promise;
}
runTransaction([array,of,validated,query,objects]).then(results => {
    // This is always triggered, and it's always an OkPacket
    // But when I check the database after UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE, the
    // queries have had no effect.
    console.log(results);
}).catch(e => {
    // This never fires.
    console.log(e);
})
```

### Things I've Tried

I've tried using a dynamic array of promise deferments to control the flow of transactions, and I've tried letting them run synchronously. All of my connections to the database are fine, and when I use the same connection or connection pool with a single GET request, it works without any problems. I began to work with transactions because running connection.query() with an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement was unsuccessful in writing to the database, which made me think I might have to force the commit (despite the fact that the same queries worked from MySQL Workbench).

The same problem presents in both single connections and connection pools: the query returns an OkPacket that shows that rows have been changed and inserted, but when I go to the database in MySQL Workbench, they aren't there.

## My Question

Am I missing something here? What I know about JavaScript says that this should be working. Is this something I should even be trying? Are there any libraries or frameworks out there that will make working with MySQL in node.js simpler? The app I'm working with is very complex, but should I just be writing my transactions by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I feel sheepish.

The answer is that there was nothing wrong with the code, but that there was an issue with the database. In MySQL workbench, during a previous debugging effort, I'd unticked Query > Auto-Commit Transactions, which was causing the transactions and statements to remain uncommitted after the first had been applied to a given row (thank you InnoDB for row-specific locks).

While the answer is not code-related, adding this after initializing the database object would have likely had the same effect:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, conn){
  if(err instanceof Error){ throw err; }
  conn.query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=1", [], function(err){
    if(err instanceof Error){
      conn.release();
      throw err;
    }
    console.log("Auto-commit Transactions Enabled.");
    conn.release();
  });
});
```

Chalk it up to me still learning how MySQL works.